# Can I use this rule in Spivak Calculus chapter 1?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In proof question no. 12 (iv), I used $|\frac{x}{y}| = -\frac{x}{y}$ if $x>0$ and $y<0$.
However I am not sure if Spivak has defined that $\frac{1}{-y} = -\frac{1}{y}$. Should I take this as a rather fundamental implication or is it derivable within the scope of chapter 1?

Comment: $\frac{1}{-y} = (-y)^{-1} = ((-1)(y))^{-1} = y^{-1}(-1)^{-1} = \frac{1}{y}(-1) = -\frac{1}{y}$

Comment: $\dfrac{1}{-y} = -\dfrac{1}{y}$ is something which has to be proven, and it can be proven based on the material in Chapter 1

Comment: @twosigma how is $(-1)^{-1}=-1$

Comment: $(-1)^{-1}=\frac{1}{-1}\to(-1)^{-1}(-1)=1\to(-1)^{-1}(-1)(-1)=1(-1)\to(-1)^{-1}=-1$ if I am right.

Comment: @Richard In general, (-a)(-b) = ab, which I believe is proven in the chapter. This implies that $(-1)(-1) = 1 \cdot 1 = 1$, i.e. that $-1$ is its own multiplicative inverse.